# InvalidOperationException on MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on a project with other students using *Team Foundation Server* online as a source code and our clients is *Visual Studio*.

I am the only one having trouble with the following exception error whenever I navigate my application or click any related to my database entity:

> "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code."

I tried to update-database, but I am getting this error also:

> "There is already an object named 'Post' in the database."

I also did Add-migration "name of new migration", but I keep getting this:

> "Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201502020217243_InitialCreate]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration."
>   The code for the InitialCreate.cs:

```
namespace Aliens.Migrations
{
    using System;    
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;        
    public partial class InitialCreate : DbMigration    
    {
        public override void Up()    
        {
            CreateTable(    
                "dbo.Post",    
                c => new    
                    {
                        PostID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),    
                        Alias = c.String(),    
                        Location = c.String(),    
                        PostDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),    
                        PostTitle = c.String(),    
                        PostMessage = c.String(),
                    })    
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.PostID);

            CreateTable(    
                "dbo.Profile",    
                c => new    
                    {
                        ProfileID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        FirstName = c.String(),    
                        LastName = c.String(),    
                        ProfileAlais = c.String(),    
                    })    
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.ProfileID);

            AddColumn("dbo.Alien", "Post", c => c.String());
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("dbo.Alien", "Post");    
            DropTable("dbo.Profile");    
            DropTable("dbo.Post");
        }
    }
}
```

The code for the Configuration.cs is:

```
namespace Aliens.Migrations    
{
    using System;    
    using System.Data.Entity;    
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;    
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Aliens.DAL.AlienContext>
    {
        public Configuration()    
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;

            ContextKey = "Aliens.DAL.AlienContext";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I Created an empty Up() method, commented out the real one InitialCreat.cs, ran it, and now I can create the next migration but I am getting the same System.InvalidOperationException whenever I click anything related to the DB. Please need help!

Comment: The error shows that when you try to create the table Post it is already in the database.So first check if there is no table with name Post than create it.

Comment: I finally solved it by what I did for each pending migration as I described it above. Then I use this lovely command Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Created an empty Up() method, commented out the real one InitialCreat.cs, ran it, and now I can create the next migration.

I finally solved it by what I did for each pending migration as I described it above. Then I use this lovely command Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges